# ¿Porque no funciona la classe table-responsive en HTML con Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

Intento construir una tabla de datos que debería ser un diseño receptivo. Es decir que usa un tamaño reducido cuando se muestra en dispositivos pequeños :
Por ejemplo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero obtengo esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy seguro que utiliso el mismo `html` codigo que el profesor y no pienso que proviene del css. Utiliso `<div class="table-responsive">` Pensé que sería suficiente. Pienso tambien que utiliso la misma versión de Bootstrap como el maestro.

Aqui esta el codigo `html`

```
    <div class="row row-content">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <h2>Facts &amp; Figures</h2>
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <th>2013</th>
                        <th>2014</th>
                        <th>2015</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employees</th>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td>30</td>
                        <td>40</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Guests Served</th>
                        <td>15000</td>
                        <td>45000</td>
                        <td>100,000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Special Events</th>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>20</td>
                        <td>45</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Annual Turnover</th>
                        <td>$251,325</td>
                        <td>$1,250,375</td>
                        <td>~$3,000,000</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
            <p style="padding:20px;"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Estoy siguiendo un curso Front-End Web UI Frameworks and Tools: Bootstrap 4, sobre Coursera. en particular el [curso sobre componentes CSS de Bootstrap](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bootstrap-4/lecture/agf7J/exercise-video-navbar-and-breadcrumbs).

Una persona llamada MCheli lo hizo bien. Es de su código (que es idéntico al mío sobre la tabla) que viene la primera captura de pantalla  [Aqui esta su repositorio GitHub para este ejercicio](https://github.com/MCheli/Full-Stack-Web-Dev-Coursera/tree/master/Front-End%20Web%20UI%20Frameworks%20and%20Tools/Week%202%20-%20Boostrap%20CSS%20Components/conFusion). Lo mio esta [sobre Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/AntoineCompagnie/bootstrap4).

Comment: Tu repositorio Bitbucket tiene acceso denegado y no se puede abrir tu código completamente. Antes de nada, voy a hacer una pregunta obvia, ¿has agregado las etiquetas de enlace para Bootstrap? ¿Has probado con otras etiquetas para comprobar si falla tu código HTML o la importación de Bootstrap?

Comment: @Víctor OoOops ! Acabo de ponerlo en público. Utiliso las etiquetas siguientes :  jQuery primero, luego Tether, luego Bootstrap JS. El repositorio de MCheli utilisa diferentes.